# how to swich from different VGA on Ubuntu 14 lts

Tags: 14.04, radeon, intel, vga

*What I checked out:*

**sudo lshw -c video**

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

**sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'**

```
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

**sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A2**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0609]
Kernel driver in use: i915
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus PRO [Radeon HD 8850M] [1002:6823] (rev ff)
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

*What I want to achieve:* I would like to know if the Radeon VGA is the main in use on my sistem. And if it's not, I would like to set it as the default one. How can I do this?

I can provide additional info, if needed.

**EDIT:**

I tried installing proprietary driver running

**sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates**

After that, I couldn't start Ubuntu normally, because "The system is running in low-graphics mode". So I had to login through terminal, running this command:

**sudo apt-get purge fglrx-***

I've also tried installing proprietary drivers from System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers but when I tried to run the Catalyst Control Center an error message says that it couldn't find any installed driver.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried xrandr ?

Comment: @lemonsqueeze what do you mean? how should I use it?

Comment: Run xrandr in a terminal and have a look at the output. With multiple monitors this is what i use to check which one(s) are being used. Might help with multiple video cards as well ...

Comment: @lemonsqueeze I've run it, but it doesn't tell me anything about VGA...

Answer (score 0):

First of all install AMD proprietary drivers by running in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
```

After that you should be able to switch adapters in Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: I've tried that, and now, when it boots up, it says that "The system is running in low-graphics mode".. I can't run in low graphic mode, i can't even reconfigure it.. Nice.

Comment: If I runsudo lshw -c video i can now see both my VGA, the integrated and the ATI one. How can I just use the ATI one?